# Crontab - simple echo not running

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

I've got such situation:
I want to schedule a job with crontab on a linux server. I'm not super-user, so I'm editing (with crontab -l, editor vim) only my crontab file. For testing, I put there:

```
* * * * * echo asdf
```

And the job is not running. Is the restart of the server needed? Or maybe some administrator move?

Comment: Check your e-mail. Output of `cron` jobs doesn't go to your terminal, since `crond` doesn't know where your terminal is. Depending on your system configuration, it's typically sent to the owner by e-mail (which may or may not be possible). `man cron` for more information.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

May be it is, cron jobs will run in their own shell. So you can't expect to see `asdf` on your console.

What you should try is

```
* * * * * echo asdf > somefile_in_your_home_directory_with_complete_path.log
```

Next check the file by doing a tail:

```
tail -f somefile_in_your_home_directory_with_complete_path.log
```

And if it's not, check if the cron daemon itself is running or is down:

```
# pgrep crond
```

OR

```
# service crond status
```

Comment: Could you tell me what should be the output of pgrep crond? I'm not getting anything but after running ps ax | grep cron I can see that /usr/sbin/cron is running. Is that ok?

Comment: You should see the pid of cron daemon -- `crond`

Comment: Did you get a pid against `/usr/sbin/cron` and how about the logfile, did it contain asdf

Comment: Yes, logfile did contain asdf. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend you to use  * * * * * echo `date` --  cron   >> crontest.log  to track all messages and check times

Answer (score 8):

If you want to echo something on your shell you could use *wall*:

```
* * * * * wall <<< "Hello from cron"
* * * * * echo "Hello from cron" | wall
```

These two lines basically do the same but the first one might not work on older shell, just choose your favorite.
Anyway, be aware that *wall* will send your message to every user currently connected.

Comment: could we execute file with command `echo test` command to the wall ?

Answer (score 1):

For me `* * * * * /bin/echo text > file` is not working...I don't know why, previleges and everything is set.
(This command is running normaly when I execute it as the particular
root user, just to clarify this.)
This can be solved by injecting the path `PATH=$PATH:/bin` in my example.

Instead `* * * * * echo text > file` is working fine, probably path issue.

Hope I helped

Comment: echo is a built-in for sh, the default crond shell. It's not in bash.